# Divs stack on top of each other

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make divs to go one after another.
I have the parent div called **services-content**, and then I have the divs (which I wanted to stack one after another) **content-row-one** and the other one called **content-row-two**.
Here's the code:

```css
.services {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.services-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content-row-one {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.row-one {
  display: flex;
  width: 85%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 20px 30px;
}

.quality-management {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.quality-management h6 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.testing-calibration {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.testing-calibration h6 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.medical-devices {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.medical-devices h6 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content-row-two {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.row-two {
  display: flex;
  width: 85%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 20px 30px;
}

.lead-auditor {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.lead-auditor h6 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<section class="services">
  <div class="services-content">
    <div class="content-row-one">
      <div class="row-one">
        <div class="quality-management">
          <h6>1. Quality Management Systems according to ISO 9000 2015</h6>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores porro quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="testing-calibration">
          <h6>2. Quality Management Systems for Testing and Calibration Laboratories</h6>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores porro quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="medical-devices">
          <h6>3. Quality Management for Medical Devices according to ISO 13485</h6>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores porro quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-row-two">
      <div class="row-two">
        <div class="lead-auditor">
          <h6>4. Lead Auditor according to ISO 9001</h6>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores porro quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="project-management">
          <h6>5. Project Management</h6>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores porro quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="quality-assurance">
          <h6>6. Quality Assurance</h6>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores porro quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I haven't added the properties to the other divs such as: **project management**, **quality assurance**, but I've added the same properties as to div **Lead Auditor** and the divs stack on top of each other.
If you need more code please let me know!
Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: remove your `position: absolute` on `content-row-one` and `content-row-two`

Comment: @Pete Could you write this comment in the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `position: absolute` from `content-row-one` and `content-row-two`, it should stack properly:

```css
.services {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.services-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content-row-one {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.row-one {
  display: flex;
  width: 85%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 20px 30px;
}

.quality-management {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.quality-management h6 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.testing-calibration {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.testing-calibration h6 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.medical-devices {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.medical-devices h6 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content-row-two {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.row-two {
  display: flex;
  width: 85%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 20px 30px;
}

.lead-auditor {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.lead-auditor h6 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<section class="services">
  <div class="services-content">
    <div class="content-row-one">
      <div class="row-one">
        <div class="quality-management">
          <h6>1. Quality Management Systems according to ISO 9000 2015</h6>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores porro quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="testing-calibration">
          <h6>2. Quality Management Systems for Testing and Calibration Laboratories</h6>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores porro quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="medical-devices">
          <h6>3. Quality Management for Medical Devices according to ISO 13485</h6>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores porro quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-row-two">
      <div class="row-two">
        <div class="lead-auditor">
          <h6>4. Lead Auditor according to ISO 9001</h6>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores porro quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="project-management">
          <h6>5. Project Management</h6>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores porro quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="quality-assurance">
          <h6>6. Quality Assurance</h6>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores porro quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```